# How to identify the line cause the Qt's warning message?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am using Qt, and sometimes it gives a warning message starts with [E] in the debug window.
Most of the time, the [E] warning message will also provides the information about the line information about the cpp file that gives this warning. Like this one:

```
at kernel\qmetatype.cpp:597 Type conversion already registered from type QPair<QByteArray,QByteArray> to type QtMetaTypePrivate::QPairVariantInterfaceImpl
```

However, usually these cpp files are Qt's own files and usually dlls in windows.
The thing is, I have never registered such a type conversion in my own code. 
And this warning seems something to do with multi-threading since it doesn't appear every time.
Is there any method, function,tools or techniques that could help me identify which line of my own source code triggered this warning?

Answer (score 0):

qWarning and others QDebug methods send their logs through message handler.

You can replace the default one with your own using [`qInstallMsgHandler`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler) and place a breakpoint inside.